# What is the name of this manga with the survivors of an epidemic gaining super powers?

Tags: absorb-ability

A strange epidemic comes and it starts to kill everyone, but the survivors gains "super powers". A boy's sister gets infected with the disease and survives, but her newly gained "power" makes her less human. To save his sister, the boy later injects the illness into himself and gains the power to take another person's power away. There is also a side character who survived the disease, and he becomes sort of immortal because nothing can hurt him, but he cannot sleep or eat. The sister's previous mutation looks like a cat.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it could be [**Absorb; Ability**](http://myanimelist.net/manga/12132/Absorb;_Ability)

> Japan wields the power of a new form of influenza so lethal that only one person out of a million can survive an infection. Kazuma, a man able to withstand the infection of the unknown virus, "Cherubim", has obtained the power to save his twin sister from facing the influenza! While Kazuma saves other people's suffering by using his new power, he will also encounter many surprising and painful things... A serious and comedic story of new abilities begins!!

This could be the cat-like mutation you are referring to:

[image]